# Shinyapps: Disconnected from Server

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

When I deploy my Shiny app the following error appears in the logs:

```
2019-05-10T18:06:12.616369+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:   there is no package called â€˜leaflet.minichartsâ€™
2019-05-10T18:09:31.759973+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Server version: 1.7.2-7
2019-05-10T18:09:31.759999+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: LANG: pt_BR.UTF-8
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760000+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: R version: 3.5.3
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760007+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: shiny version: 1.2.0
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760008+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: httpuv version: 1.5.0
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760014+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: rmarkdown version: NA
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760015+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: knitr version: NA
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760046+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: htmltools version: 0.3.6
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760239+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Using pandoc at /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760020+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: jsonlite version: 1.6
2019-05-10T18:09:31.760045+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: RJSONIO version: NA
2019-05-10T18:09:31.923629+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2019-05-10T18:09:31.928764+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:31.928766+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Starting R with process ID: '19'
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365063+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365067+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365066+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Attaching package: â€˜dplyrâ€™
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365786+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:statsâ€™:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365788+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365789+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:     filter, lag
2019-05-10T18:09:34.365790+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.367018+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.372806+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Warning in abep(dados_enem, paviment, agua) :
2019-05-10T18:09:34.367017+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2019-05-10T18:09:34.367015+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: The following objects are masked from â€˜package:baseâ€™:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.367016+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.372818+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:   NAs introduzidos por coerÃ§Ã£o
2019-05-10T18:09:34.881696+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:34.881699+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:37801
2019-05-10T18:09:40.139715+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.139718+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Attaching package: â€˜plotlyâ€™
2019-05-10T18:09:39.899589+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Carregando pacotes exigidos: ggplot2
2019-05-10T18:09:40.139719+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.140126+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:ggplot2â€™:
2019-05-10T18:09:40.140128+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.140128+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:     last_plot
2019-05-10T18:09:40.140129+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141036+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:statsâ€™:
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141039+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141039+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:     filter
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141038+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141672+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141673+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:     layout
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141674+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: 
2019-05-10T18:09:40.141671+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: The following object is masked from â€˜package:graphicsâ€™:
2019-05-10T18:09:46.576258+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Warning: Error in library: there is no package called â€˜leaflet.minichartsâ€™
2019-05-10T18:09:46.581023+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:   there is no package called â€˜leaflet.minichartsâ€™
2019-05-10T18:09:46.580805+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:   63: stop
2019-05-10T18:09:46.581021+00:00 shinyapps[533693]: Error in library("leaflet.minicharts") : 
2019-05-10T18:09:46.580807+00:00 shinyapps[533693]:   62: library
```

The error is something related with encoding, I think, but I don't know how I can fix it. I change the encoding in Options() to "UTF-8" but it doesn't work.

Comment: The error message states that the package `leaflet.minicharts` is not available on the server running the application. Are you using shiny-server or shinyapps.io?

Comment: I am using shinyapps.io I know that package is there, but I don't understand why that message appears.